# Is there any django package providing support for social auth along with the custom user model introduced in Django 1.5?

Tags: facebook-login, django-socialauth, django-1.5, django-allauth

I need Facebook auth alone for now. But we may need others like twitter and google later. From my research, both django-social-auth and django-allauth, are yet to make the compatibility changes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please let me know what issues are you running in to with django-allauth, simply file a github issue for things you encounter. Custom user models are supposed to be fully supported...

Comment: Thanks @pennersr, it's working after like about 3 days of tinkering around. I'll contribute a tutorial to your docs as soon as possible with all the lessons I've learnt.

Comment: Seems that you already solved this, just wanted to mention that django-social-auth provides Django 1.5 support with custom user models already, the support was added several versions ago.

Comment: Oh! my mistake. I should have researched better. I couldn't get it right after two days of trying it with both of these plugins. So I posted this question. Thanks a lot for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

I'm successfully using [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) with Django 1.5 custom models. The installation of allauth is a little complex, specially if the last time you touched Django was 3 years ago:-) I've submitted a pull request with some little improvements in the documentation, maybe [this may help you](https://github.com/pauloneves/django-allauth/blob/master/README.rst)